# Routing and images do not work after deployment

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have deployed a nuxt site to godaddy shared hosting (I know, right) and it all seemed to go well except that now the site displays without images and the routing doesn't work. The images are all stored in the static folder which was uploaded to the host. The nav links try and load a new page and then settle on the home page again. The site is [here](http://www.ordinarygoddesses.com.au)

The project is a nuxt frontend served by a node api with a mysql database. The api was loaded into a different folder and is working, and the frontend is getting data from the database.

To deploy the project I committed to github, then with ssh connected to the host, cloned the github repo, npm install, npm run build, and then npm start. It starts, is accessible but just no images or routing. Seems quite odd.

I upgraded node to the latest LTS (10.15.1) before build.

If anyone has an idea how to fix these issues please let me know.

Comment: You've got several console errors occurring.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter yeah, I saw those. Don't know what they are.

Comment: `npm run build` failed, if you open one of the files, like `manifest.07ddc4d80153b48fa754.js` you'll see `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line. That's what the error is all about.

Comment: Ok. npm run build did fail on the host because of a thread count issue so I ran build locally and moved the .nuxt file in with ftp.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I checked the files like `manifest.07ddc4d80153b48fa754.js` locally and they look correct, so I copied the .nuxt file to the host again and it still has the same problem. Why is this when the build was successful on my local machine?